# angularjs ng-repeat filter based on array length

Tags: angularjs, filter

I was wondering, how do I put a filter a ng-repeat that will only bring back items that have colours? I was hoping to have a checkbox above the grid entitled "Show ones with colours" that would filter the list based on the count of the colours array when it was selected, and display ALL when unselected.

```
{
   "_id": "54d13c3f3c25d5d8123a1d62",
   "name": "Barry",
   "colours": ["239, 101, 128"]
},
{
   "_id": "54d13sfg5d5d8hgf6gg",
   "name": "John",
   "colours": []
},
{
   "_id": "34d13sfg5d5d4tt6g",
   "name": "Andrew",
   "colours": []
},
{
   "_id": "44d165d5d4t77t6g",
   "name": "Gary",
   "colours": ["25, 234, 22", "5, 100, 255"]
},
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following would give everyone not having colours:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | filter: { colours: '!' }">
```

Negate it again and you get everyone having colours:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | filter: { colours: '!!' }">
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/oIl3ohe0TLMWcQlTPuY5?p=preview

Comment: That's perfect, thank you. I wasn't aware of the '!' and '!!'

Answer (score 2):

I think you an use a controller function to test for the presence of colours
so in haml/coffeescript

```
%tr{"ng-repeat2 => "item in list | filter: hasColour(item)"}
```

and hasColour is a controller function

```
 $scope.hasColour=  (item) ->
  item.colours.length > 0
```

Untested I'm afraid

Comment: The template syntax would be `filter: hasColour`